# How to get the OpenVPN *REMOTE* server version?

Tags: security, openvpn, nmap

Getting the local openvpn client version number is easy: `openvpn --version`. But I am wondering how to get the server version running **remotely**? Thanks!

I tried nc and nmap. But none of them provided me with a version number.

```bash
nmap -sV -p <server-port> <server-ip>
nc <server-port> # and sending some enters
```

Comment: For security purposes that might be hidden by design. A threat actor which scans a server and it shows the version can more easily target exploits